# Sed backreference not working properly

Tags: bash, sed

Test Data:

```
<img src=\"images/docs/mydash_grooms.png\" alt=\"\" />
```

Sed:

```
sed 's/<img\ssrc=\\"images\/docs\/\([[:graph:]]\)/<a class=\\"popup-image\\" href=\\"images\/docs\/\1\\"><img src=\\"images\/docs\/tn.\1/g' test.txt
```

Output from Sed:

```
<a class=\"popup-image\" href=\"images/docs/m\"><img src=\"images/docs/tn.mydash_grooms.png\" alt=\"\" />
```

Why is my backreference not working properly both times used?

Trying to accomplish:
Changing:

```
<img src=\"images/docs/mydash_grooms.png\" alt=\"\" />
```

to

```
<a class=\"popup-image\" href=\"images/docs/mydash_grooms.png\"><img src=\"images/docs/tn.mydash_grooms.png\" alt=\"\" />
```

Comment: Can you use things like `\s` and `[[:graph:]]` in sed?

Comment: Sure can my capture works the second time I call \1 just not the first time.

Comment: I suppose so. Do you mean to only capture a single character?

Comment: I mean to capture: mydash_grooms.png which works the second time I call \1, the extra backslashes are because this is from a mysqldump and I need to escape the quotes.

Comment: I see the need for the extra backslashes now that you've posted the input data. But if you want to capture more than one letter you need a quantifier. Try `\([^\\]\+\)` (any character but a backslash, one or more) instead of `\([[:graph:]]\)`.

Comment: Your definitely right. I wrongly assumed [[:graph:]] was quantified. I used: [[:graph:]]* to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the \ so they become actually "\\". However, you also have to escape the /, which makes the string very complex. I suggest replacing the delimiter of sed (i.e., the '/'), to another character to avoid complex strings. For example, using @

```
sed 's@<img src=\\"images/docs/\(.*\)\\" alt=\\"\\" />@<a class=\\"popup-image\\" href=\\"images/docs/\1\\"><img src=\\"images/docs/tn.\1\\" alt=\\"\\" />@g' test.txt
```

Futhermore, please replace the [[:graph:]], it was not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s|img src(.*) alt.*|a class=\\"popup-image\\" href\1>|;G;s/\n//;s|(.*/)([^>])|\1tn.\2|' file
```

Save the line in the hold space then alter the line to replicate the first attribute. Append the original line and insert the `tn.` into the file name.